# What is the difference between Observable, Completable and Single in RxJava

Tags: rx-java, rx-java2

Can anyone please explain the difference between Observable, Completable and Single in RxJava with clear examples?

In which scenario we use one over the others?

Comment: This is a perfectly valid question and should not have been closed. Although rx is a great library, the documentation and examples are unfortunately extremely poor and confusing.

Answer (score 300, accepted):

`Observable` is the generic ReactiveX building block, of event source that emits values over time. (and thus exists in every language ReactiveX extended to)
in short Observable events are:
onNext* (onCompleted | onError)? /(* zero or more ? - zero or 1)

[`Single`](http://reactivex.io/documentation/single.html) and [`Completable`](http://reactivex.io/RxJava/javadoc/rx/Completable.html) are new types introduced exclusively at RxJava that represent reduced types of `Observable`, that have more concise API.

`Single` represent `Observable` that emit single value or error.

`Completable` represent `Observable` that emits no value, but only terminal events, either `onError` or `onCompleted`

You can think of the differences like the differences of a method that returns:

- Collection of Objects - Observable
- Single object - Single
- and method that returns no values (void method) - Completable.

`Single` can be appropriate when you have task oriented Observable and you expect single value, like Network request which is performed once and return value (or error), network call is operated in one time fashion, meaning you don't expect it to return additional values over time. Another example is DB fetch data operation.

`Completable`is appropriate when you have an `Observable` and you don't care about the value resulted from the operation, or there isn't any. 
Examples are updating a cache for instance, the operation can either succeed/fail, but there is no value. 
Another example is some long running init operation that doesn't return anything. It can be UPDATE/PUT network call that resulted with success indication only.

In any case, Completable and Single are not adding new capabilities but they are introducing more robust and concise APIs, that tells more about the operations behind the Observable that the API exposed.

**Edit:**

### RxJava2 `Maybe`:

RxJava2 added a new type called `Maybe`, `Maybe` is the combination of `Completable` and Single.

In the same language like above, `Maybe` can be thought of as a method that returns 
`Optional` of some type, `Optional` is a wrapper around Object that explicitly tells whether we have some value in it - `Object` or not (instead of null).
With `Maybe` we can either have some value exactly like `Single` or have return nothing - just like `Completable`. Additionally, like both, we have the error.
`Maybe` is valuable when we want to mark that an `Observable` might not have a value and will just complete. 
An example would be fetched from the cache, we'll not necessarily have a value in the cache, so in this case, we will complete, o.w. we will get `onNext` with the value from the cache.
This is also worthy to handle non-null values in a stream with RxJava2.

### RxJava2 `Flowable`:

First, let's define backpressure.  Backpressure is a means of handling the situation where data is generated faster than it can be processed.  `Flowable` has backpressure support allowing downstream to request items.  You can read more about the differences [here](http://blog.jimbaca.com/essential-rxjava-guide-for-android-developers/#chapter6).

Comment: What about flowable?

Comment: So if I am writing in Kotlin, is `Maybe<T>`, essentially, `Single<T?>` ?

Comment: Can you consider `Single` to be a `Completable` with returned value?

Answer (score 25):

1. **Flowable** and **Observable** can represent finite or infinite streams.
   Flowable support *back-pressure*.
2. **Single** are streams with a single element.
3. **Maybe** are streams with either 0 or one element.
4. Finally a **Completable** represents a stream with no elements, i.e it
   can only complete without a value or fail.

A concise answer I found [here](http://escoffier.me/vertx-kubernetes/) on RXJava section.

Answer (score 2):

**Single & SingleObserver**

`Single` always emits only one value or throws an error. `Single` always makes sure there is an emission.

A use case of Single would be making a network call to get a response as the response will be fetched at once.

Notice here, the `SingleObserver` doesn’t have onNext() to emit the data, instead the data will be received in the `onSuccess(Note note)` method.

---

**Completable & CompletableObserver**

`Completable` observable won’t emit any data instead it notifies the status of the task either `success` or `failure`. This observable can be used when you want to perform some task and not expect any value.

A use case would be updating some data on the server by making a PUT request.